# Zip the entire server from command line

Tags: ubuntu, zip

I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my server. Is there a way to zip **everything on the server** in a single archive, preferably with a single command?

I've tried using

```
zip -r backup.zip
```

but that doesn't work, since I'm not providing it with what I would like to zip. I have also tried using

```
zip -r backup.zip *.*
```

but that only zips the files, and not the directories.

I am aware that I could go with

```
zip -r var.zip var
zip -r root.zip root
zip -r media.zip media
etc
```

Since that would be time consuming, I'm looking for an easier solution, if it exists.

**EDIT** Use of 3rd party software, like Clonezilla, is not allowed. I have to find a command line solution.

Comment: are you looking to take entire system backup ? something like image backup ? http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: Something like that, yes. I just want to have it around, so I can experiment on it, for example, on a local server.

Comment: did you check the clonezilla.org ?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, any kind of 3rd party solutions are of no use. I am limited to command line use with the stuff that's already on the server. My bad, I should have stated that in the original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd be better off creating a compressed tarball archive.

A typical command for doing this for an entire system is...

```
tar -cvpzf /backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

Comment: Would you please explain why tar is better?

Comment: tar will retain Unix file permissions plus other metadata - very useful when restoring an entire system after a disaster!

Comment: I know that. It is a suggestion to improve the post.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm testing it as I'm typing this, and everything works as I'd hoped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to zip every file and folder that is present in your server to a single zip file. You can do it like

> zip -r backup.zip /

The '/' stands for the root of the file system in linux. So the above command will start from the root and will zip all folders and files recursively. But if you are really interested to have a backup of your system, there are far more better options than zipping files and folders.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, some of the files are ignored - i get the `zip warning: ignoring special file:..`. Also, the process gets killed after 50-60 files.